# React Native - expo background - unable to access redux store value?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I am building an app with react native and expo background task manager.

I am trying to access my redux store from a functional component and dispatching values, but I keep running into an issue where the value seems to change but then I can't seem to access the true value of the variable. Below is the flow:

Click tracking -> background fires -> person gets checkedin (submitted: true) -> next ping should see the value of true and checkout (submitted: false).

Instead I keep getting a value of false in my task manager file so the code keeps checking me in instead of going back and forth.

Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Platform, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { configureBgTasks } from './task';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
const store = createStore(ourReducer);
const TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST = 'background-location-task';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    submitted: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      console.log('location permissions are granted...')
    }
  }
  
    stopBackgroundUpdate = async () => {
      Alert.alert('TRACKING IS STOPPED');
      //Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST)
  
      //UNREGISTER TASK
      //const TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST = 'background-location-task_global';
      TaskManager.unregisterTaskAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST);
    }

    //REFERENCES TO STATE
    autoTrackingCheckin = () => {
      console.log('^^firing checkin')
      this.setState({ submitted: true });
      store.dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: true })
    }

    autoTrackingCheckout = () => {
      console.log('^^firing checkout')
      this.setState({ submitted: false });
      store.dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: false })
    }
  
    executeBackground = async () => {

      //START LOCATION TRACKING
      const startBackgroundUpdate = async () => {
        Alert.alert('TRACKING IS STARTED');
    
        if(Platform.OS==='ios') {
    
          await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST, {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
            //timeInterval: 1000,
            distanceInterval: 2, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
            //deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
            // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
            foregroundService: {
              notificationTitle: 'Using your location for TESTING',
              notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and toggle tracking.',
            },
            pausesUpdatesAutomatically: false,
          });
    
        } else {
    
          await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST, {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
            timeInterval: 1000,
            //distanceInterval: 1, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
            //deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
            // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
            foregroundService: {
              notificationTitle: 'Using your location for TESTING',
              notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and toggle tracking.',
            },
            pausesUpdatesAutomatically: false,
          });
  
        }
      }

       //WHERE THE MAGIC IS SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN
        try {

          //REFERENCES FOR VARIABLES AND FUNCTIONS
          const submitted = this.state.submitted
          const autoCheckin = this.autoTrackingCheckin
          const autoCheckout = this.autoTrackingCheckout
          const reducerSubmitted = store.getState().reducer.submitted

          console.log('THE VARIABLE BEING PASSED...',reducerSubmitted)
          configureBgTasks({ autoCheckin, autoCheckout })
          startBackgroundUpdate();
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }

    }

  render() {

    //console.log('***********APP.JS STATUS:', this.state.submitted);
    console.log('***********REDUCER APP.JS STATUS:', store.getState().reducer.submitted);

    return (
      <Provider store={ store }>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <Button
          onPress={this.executeBackground}
          title="START TRACKING"
        />
        
        <Button
          onPress={this.stopBackgroundUpdate}
          title="STOP TRACKING"
        />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  const { reducer } = state
  return { reducer }
};

const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    storeCheck: (y) => dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: y })

  };
};

export default App;



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  submitted: false
};

const ourReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
    case "SUBMITTED":
      return {
        ...state,
        submitted: action.value
      }
      break;
    case "STORE_USER_ID":
      return {
        ...state,
        userId: [action.value, action.value1, action.value2, action.value3],
      }
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};


export default combineReducers({
  reducer: ourReducer,
});
```

**task.js**

```
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST = 'background-location-task';
import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const store = createStore(ourReducer);

export const configureBgTasks = ({ autoCheckin, autoCheckout }) => {

    TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION_TEST, ({ data, error }) => {

        if (error) {
            // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (data) {
            //get location data from background
            const { locations } = data;
            //let myStatus = store.getState().reducer.submitted
            //console.log('****LOCATION PINGING... submitted IS NOW:', submitted);
            console.log('****REDUCER LOCATION PINGING... submitted IS NOW:', store.getState().reducer.submitted);
            
            if (store.getState().reducer.submitted === false) {
                autoCheckin();
                //store.dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: true })
                console.log('****CHECKING YOU IN...');

            } else if(store.getState().reducer.submitted === true) {
                autoCheckout();
                //store.dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: false })
                console.log('*****CHECKING YOU OUT...')
            }
        }
    })
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const { reducer } = state
    return { reducer }
};

const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      storeCheck: (y) => dispatch({ type: "SUBMITTED", value: y })

    };
  };
  
  //export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(configureBgTasks);
  //export default configureBgTasks;
  store.subscribe(configureBgTasks)
```